# Will WeakMap save me from memory leak for parent / child relationship?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, ecmascript-6, weakmap

I have a parent / child relationship that looks like this.

```
parent.children = [child];
child.parent = parent;
```

1. Will this cause memory leak, when all other references to `parent` and `child` are removed? Only references that are remaining will be by each other.
2. If it will cause memory leak due to cyclic reference, will `WeakMap` save me?

Using `WeakMap`,

```
var parentMap = new WeakMap();
parent.children = [child];
parentMap.set(child, parent);
```

I guess that it won't since, `parentMap` has a reference to `parent`, and `parent` has a reference to `child`. There still is a cyclic reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If you remove all other references to `parent` and `child`, they are going to be garbage collected.
All modern browsers use a [mark-and-sweep](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management#Mark-and-sweep_algorithm) algorithm for the garbage collection with which cycles are not a problem.
You don't need to use a `WeakMap` (it won't help you for this anyway).

However, obviously, if a reference to either `parent` or `child` still exists somewhere, none of them will go.